# what is the use of using setters and getters in provider Class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

It is a pretty basic questions, i started off using the provider class without any getters and setters, but recently i see a lot of examples of this class using getters and setters, i remember using them in java or sth and have completely removed them as i didn't find any need?
How ever can some one explain if it is actually necessary? I have no code to post as it pretty generic question.

for the sake of an example: a typical provider class, do i need to setters and getters fro `customMarkers` ?

```dart
List<Marker> customMarker = [];

  void removeCustomMarker(String name) {
    customMarker.removeWhere(
        (element) => element.key.toString().substring(3, 7) == name);
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: You need the setter if you want to call `notifyListeners` - and usually you use provider members to force a build if something is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use getter/setters because it lets you split what is needed for each instance, for example you shouldn't notify listeners if you are only getting the value.

```
class AppProvider {

    List<Marker> _customMarkers = [];

    get customMarkers {
        return _customMarkers;
    }
    set customMarkers(String name) {
        _customMarker.removeWhere((element) => element.key.toString().substring(3, 7) == name);
        notifyListeners();
        return customMarkers;
    }

}


class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {

    appProvider = new AppProvider();

    // widget would be contained by your provider that would be listening
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Column(
            children: [
                Text(
                    appProvider.customMarkers;
                ),
                TextButton(
                    onTap: () => {
                        appProvider.customMarkers = 'new Value';
                    },
                )
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thnx! makes sense if you update your answer on how to set and get from another class it would be excellent.

Comment: no problem, updated the answer with use implementation